# sharepoint workflow for remainders

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

We have a requirement to send a mail on daily basis and weekly basis to some people. There will be 4 types of mails:

1. Daily Morning
2. Daily Evening
3. Friday evening
4. Monday Morning

can you please assist how we can we achieve it via SharePoint workflows

Answer (score 0):

The articles below for your reference.

[Reminder Workflow Pause for Specific Duration in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/remainder-workflow-pause-for-specific-duration-in-sharepoint/)

[SharePoint Workflow Weekly Reminder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0e7577e-adb6-4e63-81ab-fe037dedcd33/forum-faq-sharepoint-workflow-weekly-reminder?forum=sharepointge)